# Decile analysis - customer and revenue and vice versa

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentile

I am trying to produce an analysis which shows 2 things.

1. Deciles (or percentiles) of customers and their revenue so I can see what 10% of customer count produce the the most revenue.
2. Deciles of Revenue : how many customers produce 10% of revenue.

```html
select yeardate, decile, sum(revenue) as revenue,  count(distinct(customername)) as cust_count
 from 
(
select yeardate,
customername,
ntile(10) over (order by sum(revenue) ) as decile,
sum(revenue) as revenue
from 
(select 
year(DateStamp) as yeardate ,
customername, 
sum(Sell) as revenue
from MarginListView
where reporttype = 'Invoice' and sell >0 and year(datestamp) = 2018
group by year(DateStamp), customername) d
group by yeardate, CustomerName) c
group by yeardate, decile
order by 1,2
```

I can get the customer count deciles but not the revenue deciles....

using MS SQL server - Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of customers that produce 10% of revenue, start with the cumulative revenue:

```
select customername, sum(sell) as revenue,
       sum(sum(sell)) over (order by sum(sell) desc) as running_revenue
from MarginListView
where reporttype = 'Invoice' and sell > 0 and 
      year(datestamp) = 2018
group by customername;
```

To get the number that account for 10%:

```
select count(*)
from (select customername, sum(sell) as revenue,
             sum(sum(sell)) over (order by sum(sell) desc) as running_revenue,
             sum(sum(sell)) over () as total_revenue
      from MarginListView
      where reporttype = 'Invoice' and sell > 0 and 
            year(datestamp) = 2018
      group by customername
     ) c
where running_revenue - revenue >= 0.1 * total_revenue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon - thanks for your help.... it really did get me towards where I needed to be.

I ended with this...

```html
select 
yeardate, customername, 
sell,
cast((round(sum(sum(revenue_sub_tot)) over (order by sum(revenue_sub_tot) asc),2,2)) as decimal (2,2)) as revenue_percentiles,
cast((round(sum(sum(revenue_sub_tot)) over (order by sum(revenue_sub_tot) asc),1,1)) as decimal (2,2)) as revenue_deciles
from (select year(datestamp) as yeardate,
             customername, 
    sum(sell) as sell,
    sum(sell)/sum(sum(sell)) over () as revenue_sub_tot
      from MarginListView
      where reporttype = 'Invoice' and sell > 0 
      group by year(datestamp), customername
     ) c
  group by yeardate, customername, sell
order by 1,3
```